# How to properly define variables and add semicolons in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am being asked to define two variables and assign them values. Then I need to print both values into one console log using concatenation.

This is the code I have typed,

```
var ThingOne = "yellow"; 
var ThingTwo = "green";

console.log(ThingOne , ThingTwo);
```

as it is an online quiz the feedback I have received includes

- ThingOne is not defined
- ThingTwo is not defined
- the value of ThingOne was not printed in the console
- your code is missing semicolons at the end of each line

when I run the code it returns yellow green which is what i was looking for, but I am stumped as to what I further need to do in order to

1. define ThingOne and ThingTwo
2. make sure the value of ThingOne is printed into the console
3. and where else to add semicolons

Thanks!

Comment: Not really sure what the questions is. As you said, the code works and does what you expect. Its valid javascript. Whatever reason this quiz is giving you errors is anybodies guess.

Comment: The only thing that you haven't done is concatenating the two strings. The rest looks good

Comment: console log takes any number of strings as parameters and spits them out together, no need for concatenation.

Comment: @SpeedOfRound, seems like the quiz asks for that though

Comment: True. Im confused about this online test. Is this human feedback our automated?

Comment: Is that code under the <script> tags?

Comment: it's automated, I agree I'm confused as to why I'm getting the feedback I am, that's why I posted the question to get some human feedback @speedOfRound

Comment: Your code does exactly what it should and it's even better than the requirement asks for. Concatenating variables would be `console.log(ThingOne + ThingTwo);` but printing each be separating with commas is vastly superior, as it avoids some weird cases you can get into. Unfortunately, the online quiz sounds either broken or deliberately made to be obtuse.

Comment: Might not be that accurate my comment, but did you placed the code where the quiz is expecting it to be?

Answer (score 0):

I could see a world where someone is anal enough to want to see something like this

```
var ThingOne;
var ThingTwo;

ThingOne = 'Yellow';
ThingTwo = 'Green';

console.log( ThingOne + ThingTwo );
```

But this is not something people do, its way too verbose, your way is simpler, and simplicity is important.

Comment: I tried that earlier and got the same response. I think the quiz isn't working right. Thanks so much for the feedback!